# PHP simple strip_tags and truncate string error: connection reset

Tags: php, apache

I have following code which on save from the admin area creates a duplicate copy of the HTML content body. The problem is if I set the max_length above 160 I get connection reset error.

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is this simple too much for the apache/php to handle?

Something the content_body can be a large block of HTML text that is input from TinyMCE.

```
if($oRequest->get("contents.content_body")){
    $max_length = 255;
    $long_text = strip_tags(trim($oRequest->get("contents.content_body")));

    if(strlen($long_text) > $max_length){
        $short_text = (substr($long_text,0,$max_length));
    } else {
        $short_text = $long_text;
    }

    try {   
        $db = Db_Connections::getInstance()->getConnection();   
        $sql = "UPDATE `contents` SET `content_body_short` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($short_text)."' WHERE content_id = ".(int)$contentID;
        $db->query($sql);       
    } catch (Exception $e) {    
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have tried adding timeout (0) and this doesn't make a difference.

Error log not sure if this helps

```
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:25 2011] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 24 2010 13:33:15
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2964
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Child 2964: Child process is running
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Child 2964: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Child 2964: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 13 11:10:26 2011] [notice] Child 2964: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

EDIT: I have found that this is only happening in my local development environment and works perfectly on my Debain Squeeze server

Local setup:

- WAMP 2.1
- Apache 2.2.17
- PHP 5.3.4
- MYSQL 5.1.53
- pdo_mysql: mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $
- pdo_sqlite: SQLite Library   3.7.3

Comment: Have you checked your log file?

Comment: EDIT: added error log from logs although it doesn't seem related.

Comment: Have you checked settings in php.ini already?  Also, what is the size of your content_body_short database field -- how is it defined?

Comment: Which setting in the php.ini? Preferably I prefer to leave this set to default settings so that it will work on other servers. The content_body_short is a varchar(255)

Comment: upload_max_filesize, post_max_size are good ones to check.  Here's a helpful page: http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Comment: Thank but I have already checked this: upload_max_filesize = 750M and post_max_size = 750M

Comment: 255 is too short a size to cause any problems for Apache or PHP. Just a question, why are you catching the exception to re-throw it without any treatment ? Is it possible that there's a problem with the SQL part and you don't see it because of that ? Can you print the content of the exception if there's one and update your question with it ?

Comment: You posted apache error log, what about php one? Do you see something there?

Comment: versions of Apache, PHP and PDO extension please. Also, what is the data type of content_body_short ?

Comment: @Darhazer I have added this into the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your apache, connection close errors i got sometimes when apache childs fall down, that could be for many reasons.

- PHP 5.3.4 have some changes in the thread context, that could make it unstable
- Using php with threaded worker, php always have some troubles with threaded environments

I have been noticied you are using a win32, so could try:

- with a more stable package of apache/php (wamp and that things)
- downgrading the php.
- changing to a no threaded mpm of apache

hope this helps you, have a nice day.

Comment: What version of PHP/Apache is stable?

Comment: Honestly that differs on lot of variables when a error like that happens, depends on version, some apache stuff, so the best is try with most common used versions.